# Making a triangle with stars

Tags: java

I’m trying to make a program that makes a triangle out of stars, like this one:

> ```
>       *
>      **
>     ***
>    ****
>   *****
>  ******
> *******
> ```

I thought I had it but somewhere in my code I made a logical error that, instead of decreasing the number of spaces before the stars, keeps them infront so looks like this

> ```
>       *
>       **
>       ***
>       ****
>       *****
>       ******
>       *******
> ```

My code:

```
    System.out.print("Give a positive odd integer: ");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = s.nextInt();
    int cnt1 = 0;
    int cnt2 = 0;
    int cnt3 = 0;
    int line = N - 1;
    char c1 = '*';
    char c2 = ' ';
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (N > 0 && N % 2 == 1) {
        while (cnt1 < N){
            while (cnt2 < N-line){
                while (cnt3 < line){
                    sb.append(c2);
                    cnt3++;
                }
                sb.append(c1);
                cnt2++;
            }
            line--;
            cnt1++;
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close, your code is below with my minor modifications: (I just moved some lines inside the loop):

```
System.out.print("Give a positive odd integer: ");
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int N = s.nextInt();
int cnt1 = 0;
int line = N - 1;
char c1 = '*';
char c2 = ' ';

if (N > 0 && N % 2 == 1) {
    while (cnt1 < N){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // CHANGED
        int cnt2 = 0; // CHANGED
        int cnt3 = 0; // CHANGED

        while (cnt2 < N-line){
            while (cnt3 < line){
                sb.append(c2);
                cnt3++;
            }
            sb.append(c1);
            cnt2++;
        }
        line--;
        cnt1++;
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

This will print the following if the input is 7:

```
       *
      **
     ***
    ****
   *****
  ******
 *******
```

Your problem was that some variables weren't being reset. The red flag for me was when I saw the `cnt3` variable never being reset to 0, so it was only entering that loop once. The `StringBuilder` not being reset led to those spaces being the same length each time.

Answer (score 2):

My answer:

```
System.out.print("Give a positive odd integer: ");
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int N = s.nextInt();
System.out.print("\n");
char c1=' ';
char c2='*';

if(N>0 && N%2==1) {
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        for(int x=0; x<N-i; x++) {
            System.out.print(c1);
        }
        for(int x=0; x<i+1; x++) {
            System.out.print(c2);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Sample output using 7:

```
       *
      **
     ***
    ****
   *****
  ******
 *******
```

When you want to use `while`, replace the code between `if(N>0 ...` with this:

```
    int i=0, x=0;

    while(i<N) {
        while(x<N-i) {
            System.out.print(c1);
            x++;
        }
        x=0;
        while(x<i+1) {
            System.out.print(c2);
            x++;
        }
        i++;
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Comment: by mistake double post

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many rows: ");
    int rows = input.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++) {
        for (int x = 0 ; x < rows - i ; x++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int x = 0 ; x < i + 1 ; x++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

**output**

```
How many rows: 10

          *
         **
        ***
       ****
      *****
     ******
    *******
   ********
  *********
 **********
```

Comment: That's not the same triangle as the OP asked

Comment: @Aleksandar modified :)

Comment: @Charlie yeah still one.. :(